# Merging 2 files records by template

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

I am trying to use awk to merge two text files in a rather peculiar way, taking two lines from file1, a group of word(s) from file2 (but placed on a separate line), alternating ad infinitum.  Groups of word(s) from file2 are delimited by commas.  For example:
**file1**

```
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
Two Turtle Doves
Three French Hens
Four Calling Birds
Five Gold Rings
Six Geese a-Laying
Seven Swans a-Swimming
Eight Maids a-Milking
Nine Ladies Dancing
Ten Lords a-Leaping
Eleven Pipers Piping
Twelve Drummers Drumming
```

**file2**

```
I was born, the red planet, I am hungry, on Mars
I love frogs, they are so tasty, with gold sun, red ketchup
```

**Output file**

```
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
Two Turtle Doves
I was born
the red planet 
I am hungry
on Mars
Three French Hens
Four Calling Birds
I love frogs
they are so tasty
with gold sun
red ketchup
Five Gold Rings
Six Geese a-Laying
Seven Swans a-Swimming
Eight Maids a-Milking
Nine Ladies Dancing
Ten Lords a-Leaping
Eleven Pipers Piping
Twelve Drummers Drumming
```

Details:

- In the output file 4 additional lines created from the fields File2
  every 2 lines file1
- file1 is split into couplets of two lines, regardless of content
- A line in file2  have 4 number of groups (i.e., 3 number of commas)
- in the output file does not have commas
- A group in file2 have a fixed number of fild
- file1 and file2 may be arbitrarily long
- file2 always less than file1
- File2 fields separated by commas always occur in the same order in each 
  record ( 3,3,3,2) ie., $1 $2 $3, $4 $5 $6, $7 $8 $9, $10 S11

  In the output file to be so arranged

A Partridge in a Pear Tree

Two Turtle Doves

$1 $2 $3

$4 $5 $6

$7 $8 $9

$10 S11

Three French Hens

Four Calling Birds

I love frogs

they are so tasty

with gold sun

red ketchup

Five Gold Rings

Six Geese a-Laying

Seven Swans a-Swimming

Eight Maids a-Milking

Nine Ladies Dancing

Ten Lords a-Leaping

Eleven Pipers Piping

Twelve Drummers Drumming

- Desired behavior when you reach the end of one file but still have data in the other is unspecified- the remaining data (from file1) will be printed without changes

How do I do this?

Comment: Are **awk** is necessary? `cat file1 | paste -d, - - file2 | tr ',' '\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have put fifth line from the `file1` too early in your example.

If I'm right try this snippet:

```
awk '(NR+1)%2{print $0;getline<"file2";n=split($0,a,", ");if(n>1)for(i in a)print a[i];next}1' file1
```

output:

```
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
Two Turtle Doves
I was born
the red planet
I am hungry
on Mars
Three French Hens
Four Calling Birds
I love frogs
they are so tasty
with gold sun
red ketchup
Five Gold Rings
Six Geese a-Laying
Seven Swans a-Swimming
Eight Maids a-Milking
Nine Ladies Dancing
Ten Lords a-Leaping
Eleven Pipers Piping
Twelve Drummers Drumming
```

Comment: You're right, corrected.

Comment: I get such an effect:

A Partridge in a Pear Tree

Two Turtle Doves

Three French Hens

Four Calling Birds

Five Gold Rings

Six Geese a-Laying

Seven Swans a-Swimming

Eight Maids a-Milking
Nine Ladies Dancing

Ten Lords a-Leaping

Eleven Pipers Piping

Twelve Drummers Drumming
I was born, the red planet, I am hungry, on Mars

I love frogs, they are so tasty, with gold sun, red ketchup

they are so tasty

with gold sun

red ketchup

I love frogs

Answer (score 0):

Apart from my comment above if you prefer **awk** script

```
awk -F', ' '1;!(NR%2)&&(getline <"file2")>0{$1=$1;print}' OFS='\n' file1
```

where

- `1` - synonim of `{print $0}`:

  - *condition* = `true` (`1`),
  - *action* if do not indicated = `default` (`print`),
  - *print* without arguments = `print $0`
- `!(NR%2)` - for even lines:

  - `NR` - **N**umber of **R**ow(record)
  - `%` - calculates resedue after dividing by 2,
  - `!` - reverse result
- `&&` - logical `AND`
- `getline <"file2"` - read line into `$0` from *file2* and divide it into fields with **F**ield**S**eparator indicated as option `-F=', '` and return `1` if success.
- `$1=$1` - trick to apply **O**utput**F**ield**S**eparator: we have to do something with field(s) otherwise the `$0` will printed as it is